# What is the difference between LINQ ToDictionary and ToLookup

Tags: c#, linq

What is the difference between LINQ ToDictionary and ToLookup? They seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

A dictionary is a 1:1 map (each key is mapped to a single value), and a dictionary is mutable (editable) after the fact.

A lookup is a 1:many map (multi-map; each key is mapped to an `IEnumerable<>` of the values with that key), and there is no mutate on the `ILookup<,>` interface.

As a side note, you can query a lookup (via the indexer) on a key that doesn't exist, and you'll get an empty sequence. Do the same with a dictionary and you'll get an exception.

So: how many records share each key?

An overly simplified way of looking at it is that a `Lookup<TKey,TValue>` is *roughly comparable* to a `Dictionary<TKey,IEnumerable<TValue>>`

Comment: Also somewhat similar to a groupby?

Comment: Is the behaviour of a lookup returning an empty sequence for a missing key part of the standard contract of `ILookup<,>` or is an implementation free to throw a `KeyNotFoundException`. The [implementation in Rx](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/fcf00a1d0c95672934609b6a2dbb4b93fca55428/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Internal/Lookup.cs#L38) throws a `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: In case it helps anyone: `Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>` could be described as a dictionary of lists. So `ToLookup()` is like saying: give me a dictionary of lists. For some reason hearing it described that way helped me get it straight in my head.

Answer (score -6):

ToDictionary is <TKey, TValue> while ToLookup<TKey, T1, T2, T3, ...> is is similar to IGrouping but enumeration stays in memory.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to illustrate with the `T1, T2, T3, ...`; ToLookup and ToDictionary (the methods themselves) have pretty much the same API