# Get results of group by and add to multiple lists c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a list that has been De-serialized from an XML file in to.

```
XmlRootAttribute Root = new XmlRootAttribute();
Root.ElementName = "PersonList";

List<Person> persons;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("Test.xml"))
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new 
    XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>),Root);
    persons = (List<Person>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

My XML file

```
   <PersonList>
      <Person xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ID>4</ID>
          <Name>dasdas</Name>
          <Address>asdasd</Address>
          <Number>40</Number>
       </Person>
   </PersonList>
```

I want to group by each ID, so get all of the results if ID = '4' then add that to a PersonsID4 List
or if ID = '5' add to PersonsID5 List

```
var test = persons.GroupBy(u => u.ID).Select(p => p.ToList()).ToList();
personslist4 = test;
```

If question has been asked, please direct.

Comment: What results you get and what are expected?

Comment: I am getting no results at the moment as I do not know how to output the results. What is expected is I want to group each 'Person' by their ID and if it equals let's say '4' add that in to an List. Or if it equals to '5' add that in to another List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common thing to do after `GroupBy` is to construct a `Dictionary` that maps IDs to lists of items:

```
var test = persons
    .GroupBy(u => u.ID)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

This lets you pick a list of users with a specific ID, and to iterate all IDs with their corresponding user lists:

```
foreach (var p in test) {
    var id = p.Key;
    var list = p.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("ID={0}: {1} persons", id, list.Count);
}
```

Comment: `ToLookup` is the same functionally as a `Dictionary<key, List<value>>` and is probably better suited for the task

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I will try to implement and get back to you.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, seems [valid suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5659066/1997232), do you need `GroupBy` then? Probably you could post own answer.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That's true. However, `Dictionary` is immediately familiar to most readers, while lookup often requires some reading.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight True, either solution works fine, that's why I didn't post my own answer, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: Now that I am able to output the results, is there a way to add this to a List?

Comment: Nevermind I was being stupid, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with linq group by

// declare the dictionary

```
  static Dictionary<int, List<Person>> dictionaryPerson = new Dictionary<int, List<Person>>();
```

// if dictionary has already the key then add the list else create a new entry in dictionary

```
foreach (var person in persons)
                {
                    if (!dictionaryPerson.ContainsKey(person.Id))
                    {
                        dictionaryPerson.Add(person.Id, new List<Person> { person });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dictionaryPerson[person.Id].Add(person);
                    }
                }
```