# convert List<T> to Dictionary<string,T> with Key set to a property of T

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, keyvaluepair

```
public class Quote
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}

public List<Quote> quotes = 
    new List<Quote>(){new Quote{Price=100.00,Symbol="AAPL"},
                      new Quote{Price=200.00,Symbol="GOOG"}}

List<string,Quote> positions = new List<string,Quote>();
```

I want to set each `position.Key` to `Quote.Symbol` and each `position.Value` to `Quote`

What's the best way to convert ?

Comment: `Dictionary<String,Class>` where is this defined ? and what is `List<string,Quote> positions ` ?

Comment: `Dictionary<string,Class>` should have been `Dictionary<string,T>` I've changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand what you are asking (and that's a big if), it should be as simple as

```
var someDictionary = quotes.ToDictionary(x => x.Symbol);
```

---

[Enumerable.ToDictionary Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates a Dictionary from an IEnumerable.

Also take a look at

[Enumerable.ToLookup Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659066/what-is-the-difference-between-linq-todictionary-and-tolookup)

> Creates a generic Lookup from an IEnumerable.

A dictionary is a 1:1 map (each key is mapped to a single value), and a dictionary is mutable (editable) after the fact.

A lookup is a 1:many map (multi-map; each key is mapped to an `IEnumerable<>` of the values with that key), and there is no mutate on the `ILookup<,>` interface.