# Add List of Strings to Distinct Key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary of random strings (key), and their ASCII sum(value). From this, I want to create a new dictionary of distinct ASCII sums, and a List of all strings that match the ASCII sum.

I have attempted making a List of the unique ASCII sums and accessing my dictionary with that.

```
    private void LoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //locate file with OpenFileDialog
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog(); //create new openfile dialog

        //save file path
        if (of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = of.FileName;
            label1.Text = path.ToString();
        }

        //using streamreader and read to end, load entire contents
        //of file into a string
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            _text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //seperate massive string by newline or carriage returns
        string[] words = _text.Split('\r', '\n');


        //tolist this array of strings 
        List<string> Word = words.ToList();

        //remove all white spaces or empty lines
        Word.RemoveAll(w => w == "");

        //produce a Dictionary keyed by each line chars
        //value is the ASCII sum of the chars

        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        dict = Word.ToDictionary(key => key, value => value.Sum(x => x));

        //key is the sum, value is all the strings that have that sum
        Dictionary<int, List<string>> _Distinct = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

        List<int> uniqueSums = new List<int>();


        uniqueSums = dict.Values.Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (int item in uniqueSums)
        {
            dict.Where(x => x.Value == item).ToList();
        }

        Console.Read();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for, produces a `Dictionary<int,List<string>>`

```
var results = dict.GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Key).ToList());
```

<sub>***Note*** `ToLookup` is probably a more succinct solution for what you need. To know the difference, take a look at the following</sub>

[What is the difference between LINQ ToDictionary and ToLookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659066/what-is-the-difference-between-linq-todictionary-and-tolookup)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer some improvements that you didn't ask for... I'm assuming that you don't actually need the value of `_text` outside this method. Then you can do... (Disclaimer, done from my phone, so I can't check this)

```
    private void LoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // dialogs are IDisposable, so use a using block
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return; // deal with if they don't press Ok
            }

            // FileName is already a string you don't need to use .ToString on it
            path = openFileDialog.FileName;
            label1.Text = path;
        }

        var results = File.ReadLines(path)
            .Where(line => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)==false)
            .ToDictionary(key => key, value => value.Sum(x => x))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Key).ToList());      

        Console.Read();            
    }
```

One other tip: for `dict` and `uniqueSums`, your code creates an instance of that type, and the very next line, you throw it away by assigning the variable to something else.