# LINQ.Where is way slower than LINQ Query, but LINQ Query cannot use on the fly. how to optimize?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a populate generic method, which will populate the object based on the attribute.

```
public class TA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TB","Id")]
    public int BId { get; set; }
    [ForeignObject("TB")]
    public TB B;
}
public class TB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
// Here is the Populate generic function.
public static void Populate<TL, TR>(IEnumrable<TL> lList, IEnumrable<TR> rList)
{
    //Get the PropertyInfo from Attributes...
    //Now we have propLeftKey = PropertyInfo of TA.BId,
    //propRightKey = PropertyInfo of TB.Id, propForeignObj = PropertyInfo of TA.B
    foreach (l in lList)
    {
        propForeignObj.SetValue(l, rList
            .FirstOrDefault(r => propRightKey.GetValue(r).Equals(propLeftKey.GetValue(l))));
    }
}
//we have a HashSet<TA> TAs and HashSet<TB> TBs
Populate(TAs, TBs);
//Above function works, but horrible slow. It take over 10 seconds on a 13,000 records in TAs and 4,000
//records in TBs
//If we use a Linq query like below
//It only take less than 1 second.
var query = 
    from l in TAs
       join r in TBs on l.BId equals r.Id
            select new { a = l, b = r };
foreach (var row in query)
{
    row.a.B = row.b;
}
```

But, how can I do it dynamically based on the properties?
Or, do you have a suggestion on how to optimize it?

Comment: Moving `propLeftKey.GetValue(l)` outside the `FirstOrDefault` should already make a difference

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Selecting from a database, trying to map one class to another class? Maybe some more context around the problem and the issues that you are seeing would help answer this question

Comment: Well... In Populate you're using reflection, which will be much slower than direct object modifications that you do in your Linq underneath.

Comment: Reflection is extremely slow. A better approach would be to use compiled expressions for the reflection parts, which roughly has the same performance as hard-coded code.

Comment: Tried @RandRandom's approach, time changed from 10 to 5. Great improvement!
Gonna try the answer below.

Comment: @ckuri, can you show me how to do that?
So far RandRandom's answer is fast enough for our case, but I still would like to learn more approaches, and your sounds faster.

Comment: @Tony See my answer based on Rand Random's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is very slow, which usually isn't an issue, but becomes one if it's used many times.

It can often be replaced by using a compiled expression. A compiled expression uses reflection only exactly once when constructing the expression tree which is then compiled to a delegate.
The compilation itself is also slow, but also used only once. The resulting delegate itself has an execution performance of roughly hard-coded code. Thus a compiled expression shines when used many times.

In your case you would need to create compiled for three cases: getting the value `propLeftKey`, getting the value of `propRightKey` and setting the value of `propForeign`.

Using Rand Random's answer as base, the code would be:

```
public static void Populate<TL, TR>(IEnumerable<TL> lList, IEnumerable<TR> rList)
{
  // creates action to get left key, e.g. object getLeftKey(TA a) => a.BId;
  var instanceLParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TL));
  var propL = Expression.PropertyOrField(instanceLParamExpr, propLeftKey.Name);
  var lambdaL = Expression.Lambda<Func<TL, object>>(Expression.Convert(propL, typeof(object)), instanceLParamExpr);
  var getLeftKey = lambdaL.Compile();

  // creates action to get right key, e.g. object getRightKey(TB b) => b.Id;
  var instanceRParamExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TR));
  var propR = Expression.PropertyOrField(instanceRParamExpr, propRightKey.Name);
  var lambdaR = Expression.Lambda<Func<TR, object>>(Expression.Convert(propR, typeof(object)), instanceRParamExpr);
  var getRightKey = lambdaR.Compile();

  // creates action to set property of first param to second param, e.g. void setForeignObj(TA a, TB b) => a.B = b;
  var propForeign = Expression.PropertyOrField(instanceLParamExpr, propForeignObj.Name);
  var assignExpr = Expression.Assign(propForeign, instanceRParamExpr);
  var lambdaAssign = Expression.Lambda<Action<TL, TR>>(assignExpr, instanceLParamExpr, instanceRParamExpr);
  var setForeignObj = lambdaAssign.Compile();

  //build a dictionary
  var dictionary = rList.ToDictionary(r => getRightKey(r));
  foreach (var l in lList)
  {
    //get the value outside of a firstordefault
    var lValue = getLeftKey(l);

    //search the value inside the dictionary
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(lValue, out var foundValue))
        setForeignObj(l, foundValue);                
    else
        setForeignObj(l, default);
  }
}
```

Note: I used `PropertyOrField` because your members of TA and TB are properties and fields. If everything would be a property you could just use `Expression.Property(instanceLParamExpr, propLeftKey)` instead of `Expression.PropertyOrField(instanceLParamExpr, propLeftKey.Name)`. This would also be faster because `Expression.Property` and `Expression.Field` directly accept a PropertyInfo and FieldInfo object.

Comment: It's hard to tell how fast it could be than the previous answer based on few records, but I believe it will be faster with huge amount of records. The previous answer is good enough for my case, but in order to give latter people a good reference, I decide to choose this one as an answer. Sorry @RandRandom

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following changes

```
public static void Populate<TL, TR>(IEnumrable<TL> lList, IEnumrable<TR> rList)
{
    //build a lookup
    var lookUp = rList.ToLookup(x => propRightKey.GetValue(r));
    foreach (l in lList)
    {
        //get the value outside of a firstordefault
        var lValue = propLeftKey.GetValue(l);

        //search the value inside the lookup and get the FirstOrDefault entry
        var foundValue = lookUp[lValue].FirstOrDefault();

        propForeignObj.SetValue(l, foundValue);
    }
}
```

Using Dictionary isn't much different, but there you have to know that the key is unique or you will get exceptions

```
public static void Populate<TL, TR>(IEnumrable<TL> lList, IEnumrable<TR> rList)
{
    //build a dictionary
    var dictionary = rList.ToDictionary(x => propRightKey.GetValue(r));
    foreach (l in lList)
    {
        //get the value outside of a firstordefault
        var lValue = propLeftKey.GetValue(l);

        //search the value inside the dictionary
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(lValue, out var foundValue))
            propForeignObj.SetValue(l, foundValue);                
        else
            propForeignObj.SetValue(l, null);
    }
}
```

Differences
[What is the difference between LINQ ToDictionary and ToLookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659066)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great. drop to less than 1 second!

Comment: I was trying to build a lookup table, but don't know how to. I was trying to create the Dictionary<key, object> on the fly, but too many work so give up later. The ToLookup method is exactly what I want to use!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I have updated my answer to show how it would be possible to do with a dictionary.

Comment: OMG, I was so stupid that I don't even know there is a ToDictionary. :) I was trying to build the Dictionary using reflection...

Comment: You don't need reflection even without `ToDictionary`. All `ToDictionary` does is just call `dictionary.Add(key, value)` a lot