# How do I improve the performance of this C# code - looping through a DataTable and building a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, optimization, memory-management

I am looping through a collection (DataTable) where each item has a "group number" and building a dictionary where each key corresponds to the group number. There's about a million records in the DataTable and I am running into memory issues when this runs. I was wondering if I could get some feedback on how to make this perform better. I think maybe one issue is where I am creating a new `tempList` on each iteration.

I really appreciate any feedback here.

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<Item>> itemGroups = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<Item>>();
foreach (DataRow row in dtItems.Rows)
{
    Item item = new Item(row["ID"].ToString(),
        row["Name"].ToString(),
        row["Description"].ToString());

    Int32.TryParse(row["GroupNum"].ToString(), out int groupNum);
    if (!itemGroups.ContainsKey(groupNum))
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        itemList.Add(item);
        itemGroups.Add(groupNum, itemList);
    }
    else
    {
        var tempList = itemGroups[groupNum].ToList();
        tempList.Add(item);
        itemGroups[groupNum] = tempList;
    }
}
```

Comment: At the first sight you can try to use `List<Item>` as the dictionary value instead of the `IEnumerable<Item>`. And not to allocate a new list on the each iteration.

Comment: I suspect that `row["GroupNum"]` is returning a boxed `int`, in which case you could cast it instead of converting it: `int groupNum = (int)row["GroupNum"];`. That would save, in every iteration, some memory from calling `ToString` and some time from calling `TryParse`.

Comment: You can also try to minimize the number of allocations by pre-calculating the sizes of the lists. And then create a lists with the known capacity (so, the list will not be reallocated when you will add new elements). But this gives you a two-pass approach, so it will be slower.

Comment: It might help when dtItems would by ordered by group already. Is it?

Comment: If you're really interested in tuning, you have to consider your use of values versus references. What is "Item"? Is it a class or a struct? Are you building "collections" of values; or collections of "references" ... pointing to values? (Things like that)

Comment: This could be an XY problem. The real performance issue probably comes from using a DataTable to store a million records in the first place. That *might* be unavoidable for your use case, but given that a [DataTable has a hard limit around 16M items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-data-datatable) I would strongly consider whether it's possible to use a different data structure to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it by using LINQ. The `GroupBy` extension method is already optimized for aggregating items.

```cs
Dictionary<int, List<Item>> itemGroups = dtItems.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(row => (int)row["GroupNum"])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
        g => g.Select(row => new Item(
            row["ID"].ToString(),
            row["Name"].ToString(),
            row["Description"].ToString())
        ).ToList());
```

As other have already pointed out, don't convert values if you can cast them. If the `GroupNum` column contains an `int`, then simply cast the value to `int`. However, if a column is nullable, then it can contain a `DBNull.Value`. Let's assume that `ID` and `Name` are NOT NULL columns  but that the `Description` is optional and therefore a NULL column. Then you could optimize the creation of an item like this:

```cs
g => g.Select(row => new Item(
    (string)row["ID"],
    (string)row["Name"],
    row["Description"].ToString())
```

Note also that an `IEnumerable<T>` queries the source every time it is enumerated. An `IEnumerable<T>` is not a collection, but a way to iterate over a data source. We could have dropped the `.ToList()` and typed the dictionary values as `IEnumerable<Item>` instead. But with the consequence that enumerating the dictionary values would have executed the whole `Select` including the `new Item(...)` every time.

see also: [Understanding C# LINQ’s deferred execution](https://engineering.payoneer.com/understanding-c-linqs-deferred-execution-ba388a3ce995)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `.ToLookup()`. While it doesn't _technically_ fit the question as asked, it's very possible `ILookup` is a better fit for the problem anyway.

Comment: `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` has a `Field<T>` extension method that handles `DBNull` for you, so for example, if the description can be null, use `row.Field<string>("Description")` and it will translate `DBNull.Value` to `(string)null`. It works the same with nullable value types, too, even though their form of "null" is fundamentally different.

Comment: @madreflection, good point. `.ToString()` will convert `DBNull.Value` to an empty string, while, as you mentioned, `Field<string>` will return `null`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, yeah. Interesting links about this subject: [Difference between Lookup() and Dictionary(Of list())](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13362490/880990), [What is the difference between LINQ ToDictionary and ToLookup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5659066/880990).